# Display list of folders on the HTML Page

Tags: javascript, html, search, directory, subdirectory

What Javascript/HTML Code can be used to display the list of folders in a directory on an html page? Can Javascript do this? What I'd ultimately like to do is display the Users the web page, then filter them in a search. Right now I'm just trying to display them. Just the folders, not the contents.

Main Folder
User 1
User 2
User 3

I wasn't able to do this through a batch file and node isn't installed. Do I need Node to do this? If it needs to be done in a batch file, how can I run the batch file from Javascript?

Comment: you want to display a list of folders residing on the server? or maybe (since you said "batch") you need to run it only on your local machine?

Answer (score 0):

Answer below is only for frontend. I don't know what you want with bash and JS. Please explain that a bit more in details.

For the tree structure there is a tutorial on [w3schools treeview](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_treeview.asp).

There is also a tutorial on search bar on [w3schools search bar](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_searchbar.asp).

And for these two elements to work together you will need to know some basic JS. Here is similar example on [CodePen](https://codepen.io/husin/pen/MPEjMK).

```
<div class="dx-viewport demo-container">
    <div id="treeview"></div>
    <div class="options">
        <div class="caption">Options</div>
        <div class="option">
            <span>Search mode</span>
            <div id="searchMode"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```